# Can't extract data from nested array in Ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I am trying to extract the values of `vs_name` for every item in the array list but it looks like there is something I am doing wrong but can't figure it out.

Here is the output I want to parse

```json
ok: [localhost] => {
 "msg": {
  "AV-FAS": {
            "vs_name": "AV-FAS",
            "vs_type": "admin"
        },
  "AV-FAS-01": {
            "vs_name": "AV-FAS-01",
            "vs_type": "node"
        },
  "AV-FAS-02": {
            "vs_name": "AV-FAS-02",
            "vs_type": "node"
        }
```

Here is my code:

```
- name: populate vs list
       set_fact: 
        vs_list: "{{ vs_list|default([]) }} + [ '{{ item.vs_name }}' ]"
       with_items: "{{ output }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: **"*Extract the values of vs_name.*"**

A: Use filter [*json_query*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries). For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        vs_list: "{{ output|json_query('*.vs_name') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    "vs_list": [
        "AV-FAS",
        "AV-FAS-01",
        "AV-FAS-02"
    ]
```

---

The next option is [*mapping of an attribute*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#map). The filter [*dict2items*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) is needed to convert the dictionary to a list. For example, the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        vs_list: "{{ output|dict2items|
                     map(attribute='value.vs_name')|
                     list }}"
```

---

Q: **"*List vs_name when vs_type = 'admin'*"**

A: Add filter [*selectattr*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#selectattr) to the pipe. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        vs_list: "{{ output|dict2items|
                     selectattr('value.vs_type', 'eq', 'admin')|
                     map(attribute='value.vs_name')|
                     list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    "vs_list": [
        "AV-FAS"
    ]
```

Comment: thank you, that works. What if I then want to add the vs_name when vs_type = "admin"? Is that possible?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it's possible. I've added an example. Open a new question if you have other issues.